# Taking commisions and splitting revenue in a digital payment: Google Wallet or PayPal?

Tags: android, paypal, payment-gateway, android-pay

**Short Question:** Can you split the revenue on a payment between multiple parties?

**Explanation:**
I want to integrate payments inside an Android App, and I am liking Google Wallet as the solution. However, the app's developer wants to take a commision on the payments, and I am searching for a way to make it integrated in the app. Let's say: When a user buys a product the app's developer takes a percentage and the rest goes to the provider.

Is there a way to automatically split that payment so that a percentage reaches the developer's account and the rest goes to the provider's account? Any payment processor is capable of this? How do other developers handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With PayPal Adaptive Payments/ Chained Payments you can setup the account to split a payment between two or more receivers.

Here is the PayPal Developer information on Adaptive Payments 
[Adaptive Payments Getting Started Guide](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-accounts/gs_AdaptiveAccounts/)

Here are references about the Mobile SDKs for Adaptive Payments

[Page 19 of the Android Mobile Integration Guide has Adaptive Payments](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_mpl_developer_guide_and_reference_android.pdf)

[Mobile Integration Guide](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment)

[Mobile Integration API Payment Details Request](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/PaymentDetails_API_Operation/)

Comment: Took me too long to find out my question had been answered. Thank you.